# Enviar datos de un modal materialize al controlador

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, modal, materialize

quería saber de que manera puedo enviar la información dentro de un modal de materialize, hacia un controlador dentro del framework codeigniter usando php. De antemano muchas gracias.

Modal

```
        <!-- Modal Structure -->
        <div id="modal1" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="imgcontainer center">
                        <img src="assets/images/sessionIcon" style="width:100px; height:64px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row login center">
                            <h4>LogIn</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons iconis prefix">account_box</i>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons iconis prefix">enhanced_encryption</i>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row center">
                                **<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" onclick="<?php echo base_url();?>loginController/ingresar" name="action">Enter</button>**
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería meter un formulario que llame al controlador para añadir los datos con un button de type submit.

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
        <div id="modal1" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="imgcontainer center">
                        <img src="assets/images/sessionIcon" style="width:100px; height:64px;">
                    </div>
                    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>loginController/ingresar" method="post">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row login center">
                            <h4>LogIn</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons iconis prefix">account_box</i>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons iconis prefix">enhanced_encryption</i>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row center">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Enter</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y otra opción, menos bonita,sería meter un onClick que llame a una función javaScript que mande mediante ajax los datos al controlador. Pero te recomiendo que añadas los datos con el formulario ya que es más seguro.